# nmcli create Hotspot with HT parametrs

Tags: networkmanager, hostapd, nmcli

i have created a Hotspot with nmcli command. But the Hotspot have very low bandwidth. After debugging found out that the HT parameters isn't set.
Would like to know how to set the HT parameters using nmcli command.
eg: HT20 and HT40 parameters set in hostapd